# Does dateFromServer return the current Timezone of the person?

Tags: swift, xcode

When I am running the code below the date and time returned are in correct format but just not from what's coming from the API which in this case is the `currentVehicle.LastCommunicationDate!`
Instead of coming the time from the `currentVehicle.LastCommunicationDate!` it's just returning a random timezone I think that is getting from the Server or something like that.

The output of the code I have right now is: `2022-01-21 02:04:15` when it should have been the live time in my local timezone but it's getting a different timezone.

The `LastCommunicationDate` coming from postman is in json format: `"LastCommunicationDate": "2022-01-21T10:58:21.367",`

The time i want to be is the one from Postman just converted from json to normal time like: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

```
    let timeinterval : TimeInterval = (currentVechicle.LastCommunicationDate! as NSString).doubleValue
    let dateFromServer = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:timeinterval)
    let outFormatter = DateFormatter()
    outFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_Al")
    print(dateFromServer)
    let dateFormater = outFormatter
    outFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    print(dateFormater.string(from: dateFromServer as Date))
    let dateFromServers = dateFormater.string(from: dateFromServer as Date)
```

Comment: What are the output? What are the one you expected? Also, you can avoid all `NSStuff`, when  `Stuff` is available: `NSDate` => `Date` etc, that would avoid you later all the `as Date`...

Comment: Could you give the 2 outputs? `dateFromServer`, & `dateFromServers`

Comment: LastCommunicationDate is a time interval ? Are you sure about its value ?

Comment: the output of dateFromServers is the one i wrote, the other one dateFromServer is popping an error: Cannot assign value of type 'NSDate' to type 'String?'

Comment: LastCommunicationDate! return the date that from API , and i just needed to find the code to fix the date from the json to normal, and this code is not mine :)

Comment: @Larme mate this is the API code from postman that must come from json to normal --> "LastCommunicationDate": "2022-01-21T10:58:21.367",

Comment: Wait a minute... Are you saying that `currentVechicle.LastCommunicationDate` is `"2022-01-21T10:58:21.367"`? Because if that's the case, timeInterval is `2022`, and your whole process is wrong. You have a String Date, not a UnixTimestamp...
Could you please edit your question, and write all the values you have? `currentVechicle.LastCommunicationDate`, and the two above asked too?

Comment: @Larme edited mate, and its in json form from postman and it must be converted to the normal format and be put to the cell.timeOutlet.text = "the date and time here"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LastCommunicationDate is a string, but you are converting it to a Double. Try this instead:

```
let lastCommunicationDate = "2022-01-21T10:58:21.367"

//Create dateformatter to convert string to Date
let isoDateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
isoDateFormatter.formatOptions = [
    .withFullDate,
    .withTime,
    .withColonSeparatorInTime,
    .withFractionalSeconds
]

let isoDateFormatter2 = ISO8601DateFormatter()
isoDateFormatter2.formatOptions = [
    .withFullDate,
    .withTime,
    .withColonSeparatorInTime
]
let date = isoDateFormatter.date(from: lastCommunicationDate) ?? isoDateFormatter2.date(from: lastCommunicationDate)

//Create dateformatter to format date for output
let outFormatter = DateFormatter()
outFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_Al")
outFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let dateFromServers = outFormatter.string(from: date!)
```

Comment: hey i replaced the part of (from: lastCommunicationDate)! to (from: currentVechicle.LastCommunicationDate!) but its getting an error for nil value

Comment: Depending on exactly you're getting the nil error, this might be because A) the LastCommunicationDate is nil, or the ISO8610DateFormatter can't create a date from the string. Can you post the string value of LastCommunicationDate here? If it doesn't match the date format in my example, the dateformatter will fail to create a date from the string.

Comment: there are 2 kind of strings from the LastCommunicationDate which come from api : 1) "2022-01-21T15:36:29" 2) "2022-01-21T15:37:19.277"

Comment: OK, in that case you need two different DateFormatters - one for each format. Seems strange to have an API that returns data in different formats for the same property, by the way...

Comment: I updated my answer with a second DateFormatter for dates using the format "2022-01-21T15:36:29". It first uses the first dateformatter, and if that doesn't return a date, the second dateformatter is used.